# If condition in MySQL - can I use it like this?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

```
UPDATE kasutajad \
IF (raadioslot0 = %i) SET (raadioslot0 = -1), \
IF (raadioslot1 = %i) SET (raadioslot1 = -1), \
IF (raadioslot2 = %i) SET (raadioslot2 = -1), \
IF (raadioslot3 = %i) SET (raadioslot3 = -1), \
IF (raadioslot4 = %i) SET (raadioslot4 = -1) \
WHERE id = %i
```

Can it be used like this? If not, how could I use it to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read the documentation for the [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) statement and post a follow-up question if you have problems.

Comment: you can just try it and then tell us what problems you have got with it, if there are any. or what errors you are getting if you are getting any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use `IF` like you show. You can only set a column to an expression, and the expression may contain an `IF`. The `IF` has an "else" argument, which may be the same column. If that happens, the column is assigned its own value, in which case no change will be made.

And there must be only one `SET` keyword in an UPDATE.

```
UPDATE kasutajad SET
raadioslot0 = IF(raadioslot0 = %i, -1, raadioslot0),
raadioslot1 = IF(raadioslot1 = %i, -1, raadioslot1),
raadioslot2 = IF(raadioslot2 = %i, -1, raadioslot2),
raadioslot3 = IF(raadioslot3 = %i, -1, raadioslot3),
raadioslot4 = IF(raadioslot4 = %i, -1, raadioslot4)
WHERE id = %i
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm not very experienced with MySQL as all I've needed have been the basics.